# Ionic app scripts build error

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, angular-cli

I have this new error when trying to build my app.  I have no idea where to even start.  The error is massive making me think it's something common to many packages?

Might be worth noting I installed a package prior to this `@angular/tsc-wrapped autoprefixer` due to another error I saw.  On the `angular-cli` github issues I saw people remedy the issue with that package.

On a side note, the first error:

```
Error: ./node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.helpers.js Module not found:
```

I see that exact file when I look in my `node_modules` folder?  Is there a reason it can't find it when it exists?

```
[18:10:50]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[18:10:50]  Error: ./node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.helpers.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
            'chartjs-color' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/chart.js/src/core' resolve 'chartjs-color' in 
            '/usr/src/app/node_modules/chart.js/src/core' Parsed request is a module using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/chart.js/package.json (relative path: ./src/core) Field 'browser' doesn't contain 
            a valid alias configuration after using description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/chart.js/package.json 
            (relative path: ./src/core) resolve as module looking for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using 
            description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain 
            a valid alias configuration after using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules/chartjs-color) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias 
            configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a 
            valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' 
            doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.json doesn't exist as 
            directory /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color doesn't exist [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.ts] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.js] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.json] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color] @ 
            ./node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.helpers.js 5:12-36 @ ./node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js @ 
            ./node_modules/ng2-charts/charts/charts.js @ ./node_modules/ng2-charts/index.js @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ 
            ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.element.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
            'chartjs-color' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/chart.js/src/core' resolve 'chartjs-color' in 
            '/usr/src/app/node_modules/chart.js/src/core' Parsed request is a module using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/chart.js/package.json (relative path: ./src/core) Field 'browser' doesn't contain 
            a valid alias configuration after using description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/chart.js/package.json 
            (relative path: ./src/core) resolve as module looking for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using 
            description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain 
            a valid alias configuration after using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules/chartjs-color) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias 
            configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a 
            valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' 
            doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.json doesn't exist as 
            directory /usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color doesn't exist [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.ts] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.js] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color.json] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/chartjs-color] @ 
            ./node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.element.js 3:12-36 @ ./node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js @ 
            ./node_modules/ng2-charts/charts/charts.js @ ./node_modules/ng2-charts/index.js @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ 
            ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/dragula/dragula.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'contra/emitter' 
            in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/dragula' resolve 'contra/emitter' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/dragula' 
            Parsed request is a module using description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/dragula/package.json (relative 
            path: .) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/dragula/package.json (relative path: .) resolve as module looking for modules in 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) 
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json 
            (relative path: ./node_modules/contra/emitter) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias 
            configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a 
            valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' 
            doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter.js doesn't exist .json 
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter.json 
            doesn't exist as directory /usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter doesn't exist 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter.ts] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter.js] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter.json] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/contra/emitter] @ ./node_modules/dragula/dragula.js 3:14-39 @ 
            ./node_modules/ng2-dragula/components/dragula.class.js @ 
            ./node_modules/ng2-dragula/components/dragula.provider.js @ ./node_modules/ng2-dragula/index.js @ 
            ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/dragula/dragula.js Module not found: Error: Can't 
            resolve 'crossvent' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/dragula' resolve 'crossvent' in 
            '/usr/src/app/node_modules/dragula' Parsed request is a module using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/dragula/package.json (relative path: .) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid 
            alias configuration after using description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/dragula/package.json (relative 
            path: .) resolve as module looking for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias 
            configuration after using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using 
            description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/crossvent) no extension Field 
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent doesn't exist .ts 
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent.ts doesn't 
            exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent.js 
            doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent.json doesn't exist as directory /usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent 
            doesn't exist [/usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent.ts] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent.js] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent.json] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/crossvent] @ ./node_modules/dragula/dragula.js 4:16-36 @ 
            ./node_modules/ng2-dragula/components/dragula.class.js @ 
            ./node_modules/ng2-dragula/components/dragula.provider.js @ ./node_modules/ng2-dragula/index.js @ 
            ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/storage.js Module not 
            found: Error: Can't resolve 'localforage' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015' resolve 
            'localforage' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015' Parsed request is a module using 
            description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/package.json (relative path: ./es2015) Field 
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/package.json (relative path: ./es2015) resolve as module looking 
            for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json 
            (relative path: ./node_modules/localforage) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias 
            configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a 
            valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage.js doesn't exist .json Field 
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage.json doesn't 
            exist as directory /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage doesn't exist 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage.ts] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage.js] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage.json] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage] @ ./node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/storage.js 2:0-38 @ 
            ./node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/index.js @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ 
            ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/storage.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
            'localforage-cordovasqlitedriver' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015' resolve 
            'localforage-cordovasqlitedriver' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015' Parsed request is a 
            module using description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/package.json (relative path: 
            ./es2015) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/package.json (relative path: ./es2015) resolve as module looking 
            for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json 
            (relative path: ./node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain 
            a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver doesn't exist .ts 
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver.js doesn't 
            exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver.json doesn't exist as directory 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver doesn't exist 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver.ts] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver.js] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver.json] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver] @ 
            ./node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/storage.js 3:0-66 @ ./node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/index.js @ 
            ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/angular2-masonry/src/masonry.ts Module not found: 
            Error: Can't resolve 'masonry-layout' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/angular2-masonry/src' resolve 
            'masonry-layout' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/angular2-masonry/src' Parsed request is a module using 
            description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/angular2-masonry/package.json (relative path: ./src) Field 
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/angular2-masonry/package.json (relative path: ./src) resolve as module looking for 
            modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json 
            (relative path: ./node_modules/masonry-layout) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias 
            configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a 
            valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' 
            doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout.js doesn't exist .json 
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout.json 
            doesn't exist as directory /usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout doesn't exist 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout.ts] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout.js] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout.json] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/masonry-layout] @ ./node_modules/angular2-masonry/src/masonry.ts 13:14-39 @ 
            ./node_modules/angular2-masonry/index.ts @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ 
            ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/angular2-text-mask/dist/angular2TextMask.js Module not found: Error: Can't 
            resolve 'text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/angular2-text-mask/dist' resolve 
            'text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/angular2-text-mask/dist' Parsed request is 
            a module using description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/angular2-text-mask/package.json (relative path: 
            ./dist) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/angular2-text-mask/package.json (relative path: ./dist) resolve as module looking 
            for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json 
            (relative path: ./node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore doesn't exist 
            .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore.js doesn't 
            exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore.json doesn't exist as directory 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore doesn't exist 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore.ts] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore.js] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore.json] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore] @ 
            ./node_modules/angular2-text-mask/dist/angular2TextMask.js 17:21-64 118:21-64 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ 
            ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/@angular/animations/@angular/animations/browser.es5.js Module not found: 
            Error: Can't resolve 'tslib' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/animations/@angular/animations' resolve 
            'tslib' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/animations/@angular/animations' Parsed request is a module 
            using description file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/animations/package.json (relative path: 
            ./@angular/animations) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description 
            file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/animations/package.json (relative path: ./@angular/animations) 
            resolve as module looking for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias 
            configuration after using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using 
            description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/tslib) no extension Field 
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib doesn't exist .ts 
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.ts doesn't exist 
            .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.js doesn't 
            exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.json 
            doesn't exist as directory /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib doesn't exist [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.ts] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.js] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.json] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib] @ 
            ./node_modules/@angular/animations/@angular/animations/browser.es5.js 1:0-33 @ 
            ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js @ 
            ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/@angular/common/@angular/common.es5.js Module not 
            found: Error: Can't resolve 'tslib' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/common/@angular' resolve 'tslib' 
            in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/common/@angular' Parsed request is a module using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/common/package.json (relative path: ./@angular) Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/common/package.json (relative path: ./@angular) resolve as module looking 
            for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json 
            (relative path: ./node_modules/tslib) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias 
            configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid 
            alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a 
            valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.json doesn't exist as directory 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib doesn't exist [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.ts] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.js] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.json] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib] @ 
            ./node_modules/@angular/common/@angular/common.es5.js 1:0-33 @ 
            ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js @ 
            ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js Module not found: Error: Can't 
            resolve 'tslib' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/@angular' resolve 'tslib' in 
            '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/@angular' Parsed request is a module using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/package.json (relative path: ./@angular) Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/package.json (relative path: ./@angular) resolve as module 
            looking for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative 
            path: ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description 
            file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/tslib) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain 
            a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' 
            doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.js doesn't exist .json Field 
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.json doesn't exist as 
            directory /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib doesn't exist [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.ts] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.js] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.json] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib] @ 
            ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js 1:0-33 @ 
            ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js @ 
            ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
            'tslib' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular' resolve 'tslib' in 
            '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular' Parsed request is a module using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/core/package.json (relative path: ./@angular) Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/core/package.json (relative path: ./@angular) resolve as module looking 
            for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json 
            (relative path: ./node_modules/tslib) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias 
            configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid 
            alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.ts doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a 
            valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.js doesn't exist .json Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.json doesn't exist as directory 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib doesn't exist [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.ts] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.js] 
            [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib.json] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib] @ 
            ./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 1:0-33 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ 
            ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.es5.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
            'tslib' in '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular' resolve 'tslib' in 
            '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular' Parsed request is a module using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/forms/package.json (relative path: ./@angular) Field 'browser' doesn't 
            contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/forms/package.json (relative path: ./@angular) resolve as module looking 
            for modules in /usr/src/app/node_modules using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: 
            ./node_modules) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: 
            /usr/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules) using description file: /usr/src/app/package.json 
            (relative path: ./node_modules/tslib) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
```

Comment: Have a go deleting `node_modules` and then running `npm install`

Comment: Still got the same error

Comment: Seeing some similar problems when upgrading NPM.